# Comparison of numeric variables

Tags: r, comparison-operators

I need to left join results of `table` to generated sequence. Because it did not work as expected (some rows were missing), I tried to compare values in both variables. Why some values of `df$c` are not equal to values generated using `seq()`?

```
# Sample data
a <- runif(100)
b <- runif(100) > .5
step <- .1

# This is what I do in my real task
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(trunc(a / step) * step, b))
df$c <- as.numeric(rownames(df))

# Would like to join, but comparsion of df$c and generated sequence
# return FALSE for some elements.
df$c == seq(0, 0.9, step)

# Returns>  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Good question, but already answered. :)

Comment: @Joshua Thank you - I was googling wrong words. For anyone interested - in `merge` I am now joining `round(df$c, 3)` and `round(seq(0, 0.9, step)` and it works.